# Compute integral with indicator function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Consider the following set
$$
A = \left\{(x, y)\, :\, 0 < y < f(x)\right\}
$$
I woul like to compute this integral
$$
\int \mathbb{1}_{A}(x, y) dx
$$
where $f(x)$ is a positive function with finite integral. Can I simplify this?

## Visualizing this

[image]

Comment: Hint: Can you visualize $A$ geometrically? What about the integral? Remember the integral of a characteristic function is just the measure of the set.

Comment: For $y$ fixed, Your integral is $\lambda(x: f(x)>y)=\lambda\big(f^{-1}(y,\infty)\big)$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I added a picture!

Comment: @Physics_Student: the set described by the thick line is not $A$, but $A^y=\{x:f(x)>y\}$ under that assumption that the dotter horizontal line corresponds to the hight $y$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz aren't these two sets the same? Well apart from $y$

Comment: It is the measure of the set $\{x | f(x) = y \}$.

Comment: Nope $A$ as you defined it, is a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+$ (or $X\times\mathbb{R}_+$ if integrating over an abstract space $(X,\mathscr{B}),\mu)$). $A^y$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (or $X$ if integrating over abstract space). $A^y$ is a cross section. Another cross section $A_x$ is defined as $A_x:=\{y>0: f(x)>y\}=(0,f(x))$

Comment: $A$ is the region between the curve that you drew and the $x$-axis (shot can out a grade shade if you can. I am terrible at drawing pictures in LaTeX.